# node -v not matching nvm selection

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm trying to switch my node version using nvm (on MacOS) but after setting the node, the version is not the selected

```
$ nvm which node                                                     [10:39:48]
/Users/foobar/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node

$ nvm list                                                           [10:44:23]
       v18.17.1
->       system
default -> 18.17.1 (-> v18.17.1)

$ node -v                                                            [10:40:01]
v14.17.5
```

What am I doing wrong?
I've also brought up nee terminals and the node version is still incorrect.

Comment: Have you uninstalled the node binary installed without using `nvm`?

Comment: Yes - by  using `brew remove node --force`

Comment: Try running `which node` instead of `nvm which node` to check where this is coming from.

Comment: `which node` was VERY useful in solving my issue.  Thanks!